# Reverse pagination order in Django Endless Pagination

Tags: django, pagination, django-comments, django-pagination, django-endless-pagination

The default pagination for Django Endless Pagination(which is working perfect for me) shows the oldest object first and then pagniates through newer ones i.e, the last page contains the newest object. I am trying to use this to paginate comments and would like to show the newest comments first and then paginate through the older ones (like on Facebook). To me, it seems a pretty standard ask, but I haven't been able to find any solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you looked to the oficial django paginator? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any code, it's tough to give you a concrete solution, but the general it will order things however the queryset happens to be ordered.  Just use `order_by` in your query in your view to sort it however you desire.